# ORC file read from WebHDFS Rest API

Tags: java, hdfs, orc, webhdfs

I have a task of reading orc file from my java program , I am able to read successfully if the orc file is in my local machine using below code, where below targetFilePath is the file path and name of the file.

```
Reader orcReader = OrcFile.createReader(fs, targetFilePath);
        String codec = String.valueOf(orcReader.getCompression());
        String schemaString = orcReader.getObjectInspector().getTypeName();
        String storage = STORAGE_TYPE;
        String abstractPath = targetFilePath.toUri().getPath();
        FileStatus fstat = fs.getFileStatus(targetFilePath);
```

I have further requirement that ORC file will be in Hadoop env and i wanted to use WebHDFS API, but problem is ORC reader has no api which can read from streams.

Please help how can i read streams and read orc file from WebHDFS.

Thanks

Comment: Why WebHDFS and not Spark or Hive?

Comment: 1. WebHDFS is faster and i am able to access that with there rest api from my local machine, Cluster is residing somewhere else. I cannot put my java files in server where cluster is existing

Comment: Based on my metrics, WebHDFS is far slower than NameNode RPC. You don't need Java. You can use Python, GoLang, Ruby, etc. I am simply suggesting JDBC or RPC rather than HTTP

Comment: Thanks for workaround OneCric, but at this moment of time when the project is going with complete Java , i cannot change to other's. On a side note I am also trying to establish connection to Hive using the JDBC which is a other thing altogether. The reason for me to connect to WebHDFS is i need to read AVRO and ORC files which cannot be queried similar to what we can query from Hive tables

Comment: What do you mean "similar"? Are you saying you have not used the [Avro](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe) and [ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC) serdes? Reading a binary file over HTTP will not work out very well